# Activator fails creating new project with java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

Activator fails when creating a new project when running command from path

```
nschejtman@nschejtman-Lenovo-V570:~/projects$ activator new
Fetching the latest list of templates...

Browse the list of templates: http://typesafe.com/activator/templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
  1) minimal-akka-java-seed
  2) minimal-akka-scala-seed
  3) minimal-java
  4) minimal-scala
  5) play-java
  6) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
> 6
Enter a name for your application (just press enter for 'play-scala')
> 
OK, application "play-scala" is being created using the "play-scala" template.

ProcessError(Failed to create /home/nschejtman/projects/play-scala: Could not 
create directory /home/nschejtman/projects/play-scala,
Some(java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create directory 
/home/nschejtman/projects/play-scala))

Failed to clone the template. Make sure you have internet access and please 
try again.
```

If I run the command from the activator home it works OK. I've added the following line to my .bashrc

export PATH=$PATH:/home/nschejtman/devel/activator-1.3.4-minimal/

Comment: Maybe Play/Activator doesn't have write access to the path `/home/nschejtman/projects/play-scala`?

Comment: @Kris yes, it was exactly that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be one of the silly things one forgets: Maybe Play/Activator doesn't have write access to the path /home/nschejtman/projects/play-scala in your file system?